# How do I iterate through this table and extract all info for a slideshow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multidimensional-array

I have an array in jquery that consists of subsets of answers to questions but before the 
user gets to the q&a I want to display the answers to the user for memorisation. Can someone explain how 
I can iterate through the array and extract each image in turn?

```
var imageAnswers = {"q1toQn": [
    {"q1": [
        {"src": "./images/q1/cow", "alt": "cow", "id": "cow"},
        {"src": "./images/q1/horse", "alt": "horse", "id": "horse"},
        {"src": "./images/q1/pig", "alt": "pig", "id": "pig"},
        {"src": "./images/q1/sheep", "alt": "sheep", "id": "sheep"}
    ]},
    {"q2": [
        {"src": "./images/q2/apple_", "alt": "apple", "id": "apple"},
        {"src": "./images/q2/pear_", "alt": "pear", "id": "pear"},
        {"src": "./images/q2/orange_", "alt": "orange", "id": "orange"},
        {"src": "./images/q2/pineapple_", "alt": "pinaapple", "id": "pineapple"}
    ]},
    {"q3": [
        {"src": "./images/q3/chair", "alt": "chair", "id": "chair"},
        {"src": "./images/q3/bookcase", "alt": "bookcase", "id": "bookcase"},
        {"src": "./images/q3/chest", "alt": "chest", "id": "chest"},
        {"src": "./images/q3/table", "alt": "table", "id": "table"}
    ]}, ...
```

etc etc

and here is what I'm doing to try to get the info out:

```
    var infoTableIndex = 0;

j(function(){
    j("#nextButton").click(
        function(){
            j("#slideshow").not(":animated").animate({"left": "500px", "opacity": "0.3"}, 1000,
            function(i){
                infoTableIndex++;

                j("#slideshow").attr("src", imageAnswers.q1toQn[infoTableIndex].q1[i+1].src + ".png");
                j("#slideshow").css("left", "-500px");
                j("#slideshow").animate({"left": "40px", "opacity": "0.1"}, 500);
            })
        }//no sc
    );
});
```

The error I get is:

> TypeError: Result of expression
>   'imageAnswers.q1toQn[infoTableIndex]'
>   [undefined] is not an object.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you debug `infoTableIndex` and `i` to ensure you are getting what you expect?

Comment: I would if I knew how. Username: ChrisP <- n00b :(

Answer (score 1):

`.animate()`'s "complete" callback function doesn't send any index nor parameter of any kind, so your `i` is undefined.

If it has to be a sequential param, you could use the same `infoTableIndex` var, so you'd have:

```
imageAnswers.q1toQn[infoTableIndex].q1[infoTableIndex+1].src
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: It'd be good if you explain better the logic of your slideshow and give an example

Comment: When I click a next button I want to see the next (or a random, it doesn't matter) image from the array (q1-1, q1-2, q1-3... q4-1,q4-2, q4-3... etc) until the last image. Each picture will also provide a word (it's a language learning app). The user reads through and then clicks another button to go to a quiz where their memory is tested on the what they saw/read in the slideshow. It's basically a simple 1 image at a time slideshow, taking the image from the array as shown in the code above.